# Find first column for each row in a data set that has a specific value

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm working on time series data. I have a dataset in the form of:

Country, 01.01.2020, 02.01.2020, 03.01.2020, 04.01.2020, ...

USA,      0,           3,           3,           3,

BRA,      0,           0,           0,           0,

BNE,      0,           0,           0,           4,

CHN,       0,           3,           3,           4,

.

.

.

I now would now like to first only keep rows that at any of their columns have either a 3 or a 4. (3 or 4 correspond to events that I am trying to track)
For all these countries (rows) I would need to know the date (column) where they first had a 3 or a 4. So the leftmost column with a 3 or 4.
I'm trying to produce a histogram that shows the distribution of these dates over all countries.
So my final goal would be to have a list that gives me the number of countries that had their first 3 or 4 on each of the days (columns)

Thanks for any help

Comment: Hi, it would be nice you could create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it would help people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach with `tidyverse`.  First, would use `pivot_longer` to put your dates into columns. Use `mutate` to convert the date character to Date format, noting the column names are improper (depending on how your data frame looks, this may be different than what I have). You can `filter` rows that have values of interest (3 or 4), ensure dates are arranged in order, and then select the first row for each `Country`. Finally, you can `group_by(date)` and determine the number of countries found for each date.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Country, names_to = "date") %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "X%m.%d.%Y")) %>%
  filter(value == 3 | value == 4) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  group_by(Country) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(num_countries = n())
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  date       num_countries
  <date>             <int>
1 2020-02-01             2
2 2020-04-01             1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did exactly what I wanted.